# How can i print by group in awk or csh?

Tags: awk, csh

Hi all im new in awk and cshell, can anyone know how to print the output by group like that ?
My input file:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
AD 4
AD 5
B 6
B 7
B 8
B 9
A 10
AC 11
AC 12
```

Output desire i want print by group if it have same in $1:

```
#########
#### A 
#########
1
2
3
10
#########
#### AD
#########
4
5
#########
#### B
#########
6
7
8
9
#########
#### AC
#########
11
12
```

I have tried with this code:

```
set my_sort = `cat input | awk '{print $1}' |sort |uniq`
foreach name ($my_sort)
       echo "##########"
       echo "#### $name"
       echo "##########"
       awk '/^'$name'/ {print $0} input           # i want print all line to check
end
```

but the output not like i want:

```
#########
#### A 
#########
A 1
A 2
A 3
AD 4
AD 5
A 10
AC 11
AC 12
#########
#### AC
#########
AC 11
AC 12
#########
#### AD
#########
AD 4
AD 5
#########
#### B
#########
B 6
B 7
B 8
B 9
```

Any know where is my problem and can I optimal if can with awk ? Thanks all and have a nice day

Comment: Don't write scripts using [t]csh, it's not what it was designed for. See any of the results from googling it - https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2,2n file |
    awk '$1!=prev{printf "########\n#### %s\n########\n", $1; prev=$1} {print $2}'
########
#### A
########
1
2
3
10
########
#### AC
########
11
12
########
#### AD
########
4
5
########
#### B
########
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! it work perfectly. But can you explain detail of this for me if you can ? I want to know more. Thank you again

Comment: You're welcome. It's extremely basic awk syntax so please take a look at the man page and then ask if you have any specific questions afterwards as it wouldn't make sense to explain the fundamentals of awk in every answer.